# very bad surface quality

Tags: surface

I am getting very bad surface quality on an Ender 3 Pro.
My last prints are a disaster like in the picture. The filament is PLA.
How to improve from here?

For reference: the filament was bought a few days ago and I did not dry it. I am using a 0.4 mm nozzle at a temperature of 215 °C. Speed is set to 50 mm/s.

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model with very bad surface quality]

Comment: Consider to edit your question with specific settings such as speed, nozzle and bed temperatures and if you've recently dried the filament. Underextrusion appears to be the result, but the causes are varied.

Comment: Please comment on the filament diameter in the slicer you used and inspect the extruder of the Ender, it has a poor extruder design, please look for gear wear or broken lever, the latter is common for these extruders.

Comment: You might want to increase the flow rate, 215C is towards the end of the range for PLA check the spec sheet. If all fails make sure nozzle is not clogged.